# Java - How to use an array in 1 method, in another or even multiple other methods?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

I am trying to use the 2D array "myArray" which is created in the createArray method - in all other methods in the program. I looked over some other stack overflow answers similar to this, and nothing I have tried has worked. Every time I try to pass the array to the other methods, it is unresolved.

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RandomArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createArray();
        calculateVariables();
        callArray();
    }

    public static void createArray(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of rows: ");
        int rows = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number of columns: ");
        int columns = scan.nextInt();

        int count = 0;
        int[][] myArray = new int[rows][columns];

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
                myArray[row][col] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                System.out.print(myArray[row][col] + "\t");

                if (rows > 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The number of elements in the array: " + count);
        }
    }
    
    public static void calculateVariables(){
        int sum = 0;
        int min = myArray[0][0];
        int max = myArray[0][0];
        int below50 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {

                if (max < myArray[i][j]) {
                    max = myArray[i][j];
                }

                if (min > myArray[i][j]) {
                    min = myArray[i][j];
                }

                sum = sum + myArray[i][j];

                if (myArray[i][j] < 50) {
                    below50++;
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("The average number is: " + sum / count);
        System.out.println("the min is " + min);
        System.out.println("the max is " + max);
        System.out.println("the number of entries below 50 is: " + below50);
        System.out.println();
        }
        
    public static void callArray(){
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a row number: ");
        int row1 = scan2.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter a column number: ");
        int col1 = scan2.nextInt();

        if ((row1 > myArray.length) && (col1 > myArray.length)) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, I cant retrieve that value! You entered a bad index.");
        }

        if ((row1 < 0) && (col1 < 0)) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, I cant retrieve that value! You entered a bad index.");
        } else System.out.println("The entry at that row and column is: " + myArray[row1][col1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are never passing the array to any other method. Since the array is defined as a method-local variable, other methods cannot access it, without it being passed

Comment: The obvious answer, especially for a method named "create array", is to return the array you just made: `int[][] createArray(){...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating that array in the scope of the `createArray` method, that means that `myArray` is a defined variable only within that method. If you'd like to use it in other methods, you can either define it inside the `main` method as the return value of `createArray` and pass it in each call:

```
int[][] myArray = createArray();
calculateVariables(myArray);
callArray(myArray);
```

or define it as a class field:

```
static int[][] myArray;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createArray();
    calculateVariables();
    callArray();
}

public static void createArray(){
    //... 
    myArray = new int[rows][columns];
    //... 
}
```

Comment: Considering the method `createArray()` is static, you'll need to add the `static` modifier in front of the array definition for the second example.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Slipped from my mind

Comment: Thank you so much! I opted for the second example - class field.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Make `myArray` a static field in your class, so every static method in the class can see it.
2. Return `myArray` from the `createArray` method, store it in a local variable in `main`, and pass it as a parameter to each of the other methods.

i.e.:

```
static int[][] createArray() { ... }
static void calculateVariables(int[][] myArray) { ... }
...
int[][] myArray = createArray();
calculateVariables(myArray);
callArray(myArray);
```

Option 2 is far superior to option 1, as it:

- makes it clear what data the functions depend on
- prevents you calling `calculateVariables` without having created the array.
- allows you to have many arrays used at once

Comment: Could you provide a code example for option two? I think it would be far clearer that way :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply!